# Joining SQL Server UDF with params

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

I have a code I cannot resolve. Can anyone help me, please?

Code:

```
SELECT 
    s.* 
FROM 
    tabD d
    ,tabP p
    ,dbo.myFunc(d.col1) f 
    ,tabS s
WHERE 1=1
    and p.D_ID=d.ID
    and s.ID=f.ID
```

`myFunc` is an UDF returning a table (containing, inter alia, column ID)

The problem is, that the `dbo.myFunc(d.col1)` call causes an error

> The multi-part identifier "d.col1" could not be bound.

How to rearrange the code to work fine?

(Running on SQL Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [APPLY](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-apply-basics/) to pass in row by row parameters into a UDF

And of course use ANSI-92 style joins as a matter of course. Mixing APPLY and the old style "join in the where clause" will cause you headaches: even more so than just not using explicit JOIN syntax

```
SELECT 
    s.* 
FROM 
    tabD d
    JOIN
    tabP p ON p.D_ID=d.ID
    CROSS APPLY
    dbo.myFunc(d.col1) f
    JOIN
    tabS s ON s.ID =f.ID
```

Comment: My code was just an sample. The real code is much longer. Can I let stay the where clause like this?:
    `SELECT 
        s.* 
    FROM 
    tabD d
        ,tabP p
        CORSS APPLY dbo.myFunc(d.col1) f 
        ,tabS s
    WHERE 1=1
        and p.D_ID=d.ID
        and s.ID=f.ID`

Comment: @MartinProcházka: It will bite you later, but hey, it's your code

Answer (score 0):

may be this also works

```
  SELECT 
    d.*,
    (Select P.Id from tabP P where P.ID = d.id) P,
    (Select S.ID from tabs S where S.ID = d.id) P

FROM 
    tabD d
    OUTER APPLY
    dbo.myFunc(d.col1) f
WHERE 1=1
    and P.ID=d.ID
    and S.ID=f.ID
```